# Very slow from query to c.JSON

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gin

I'm querying my database using Gorm and then using gin's c.JSON to marshal the structs to json.

It's a large query with not so much result ( < 100k ) and i'm having an issue with the time it takes ( 6-10 seconds ) to marshal the data.

I have no idea where to start to resolve the issue.

```
    [2019-07-02 14:41:04]  [946.63ms]   SELECT  big slow query
    [62861 rows affected or returned ]
    [GIN] 2019/07/02 - 14:41:11 | 200 |   7.92347114s |  ip | GET      /api/date/2019-05-30


    [2019-07-02 14:40:44]  [660.47ms]   SELECT big slow query
    [7583 rows affected or returned ]
    [GIN] 2019/07/02 - 14:40:54 | 200 | 10.841096216s |  ip | GET      /api/dailies

    [2019-07-02 14:43:49]  [154.13ms]   SELECT simple query
    [11 rows affected or returned ]
    [GIN] 2019/07/02 - 14:43:49 | 200 |  158.256792ms |  ip | GET      /api/dailycount
```

As you can see query 1 and 2 resolve in 600-900 ms , it's slow but it can be optimised separately.
The issue is that the response of the server take 7.9 and 10.8s ..!
For the smaller query there isn't much difference but i'm not getting why this is happening.

The go code for one of the route is pretty straightforward and similare for all routes :

```
    var alertList []AlertJson
    dbInstance.Debug().Raw("SELECT big query").Scan(&alertList)
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"alerts": alertList})
```

10.2 second for the second query with 7583rows to marshal seem pretty insane to me.

Comment: That measurement probably includes the time it takes to transfer the json over the wire as well. How large are the responses in terms of bytes? You should also add the definition of AlertJson to the question.

Comment: In this situation I would also try to implement this without gorm and instead use the stdlib's `database/sql` package. It may very well be that under the hood gorm is relying too much on reflection.

Comment: You could also speed things up by not using gorm or gin, and instead begin streaming your JSON response as soon as you get your first result from the database.

Comment: If you want to know how long the query took **on the server** run `explain (analyze) select ...`

Comment: Using `pprof` you can profile a request to see exactly where your service is spending its time https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/

Answer (score 0):

There was immense lag on my server provider and just in fact the 10 second is indeed the delay for me to receive the data as mentioned by peter.